# How to Push branch of one repository to a new branch in another repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch "tree" in my testing repository.

Now i want to move that branch to a new repository "react-tree-component" as the brand new master branch,

```
Testing > tree
MOVE TO
react-tree-component > master
```

Use Case : I have a testing repo in which I treat as rough work..but sometime the work turns out to be useful and can be a starting point of another project deserving its own repo....therefore need this

how can i do this?

Comment: Try to add the new remote (`git remote add react-tree-component <url>`) and push the branch (`git push -u react-tree-component tree:master`), assuming master does not exist there.

Comment: @mszymborski , thanks got it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to add the new "target" remote:

`git remote add react-tree-component <url>`

And then push with rename:

`git push -u react-tree-component tree:master`